# Odd Result After Setting Ranges Equal

Tags: excel, vba

This is some simple code to add a range from a report to a running list in a main file. There are no errors in the code, but for some reason after the values get transferred, it turns all of the values in the entire 5,000+ items list in the main file to "N/A" errors, even though they are all just values. I double checked the formatting and range sizes and everything seems fine. Has anyone had an error like this?

```
        Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        Dim wkb As Workbook
        Dim currentRowCount As Integer
        Dim atsStartRow As Integer
        Dim reportRange As Range
        Dim atsRange As Range
        Dim atsName As String
        Dim productionCount As Integer
        Dim endRow As Integer

        atsName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

        For Each wkb In Workbooks
            If Left(wkb.Name, 4) = "Prod" Then
                With wkb.Sheets(1)
                    currentRowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
                    productionCount = (.Cells(2,4).End(xlDown).Row) - 1
                    Set reportRange = .Range(.Cells(2,4), .Cells(currentRowCount, 10))
                End With

                With Workbooks(atsName).Sheets("ProductionSummaryReport")
                    atsStartRow = (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row) + 1
                    endRow = (atsStartRow + productionCount) - 1
                    Set atsRange = .Range(.Cells(2,4), .Cells(endRow, 10))
                End With

                atsRange.Value = reportRange.Value
            End If
        Next wkb
        MsgBox "Script finished."
        End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you're reporting some "bug", you should provide a minimal example to reproduce it. So you should probably show what data one has to input to run this and get the result you experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the sizes of your ranges at the time you're assigning the values. So, set a breakpoint in the editor on the line `atsRange.Value = reportRange.Value` and check at that point the following values (maybe add them as watches?)

- atsRange.Rows.Count
- atsRange.Columns.Count
- reportRange.Rows.Count
- reportRange.Columns.Count

I suspect that your dimensions are mismatched quite heavily. And if you assign the values of a smaller range into those of a larger range, any cells beyond the area in the smaller range will be set to '#N/A'. So if atsRange is much bigger than reportRange, you'll get a bunch of '#N/A' values.

Comment: Yep that's what I overlooked. Thanks!